# duplicating and splitting a line if a cell has a specific value in Excel

Tags: excel, csv

I'm looking at writing something for the below in Python but I'm hoping that it can be done natively in Excel.

I have a sheet that contains multiple rows. Within column C, the recipient is listed. Each row basically contains data relating to the sender and recipient**S** of emails and so, there may just be one recipient or multiple:-

[original data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNru3.png)

What I'd like to do is to split on Column C (recipients) that contain multiple recipients into their own unique row and so, looking at the `joe.bloggs@hotmail.com,jack@gmail.com` example, I'd like this to be split on the `,` and for the two email addresses to be in their own rows **together with** the other values that exist in the row.

So, using the example above, I'd run the function/whatever is required and I'd end up with 6 distinct rows containing:-

[What i'm looking to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xclgo.png)

together with the content of the other values in the source row being copied over

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance

**UPDATE** - I've been Googling this and think a Power Query may be the way forward.... I'm researching this further now

Comment: If it's a `.csv`, open it in a text editor and do a search for `, ` and replace with a carriage return

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad. There are other values in the row and so, if I do a replace for a return carriage in a texteditor, this will also return everything else in that row.

Comment: You could still do it with a GREP search that looks for `, ` preceded by an e-mail. For a better answer, post sample data.

Comment: Edited with screenshots to try and help. Thanks @cybernetic.nomad